# RTI DDS Connext Host on PI

Tags: raspberry-pi, data-distribution-service

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to run an RTI DDS example on Raspberry PI:

```
NDDSHOME=/home/pi/RTI/ndds.5.0.0
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/pi/RTI/ndds.5.0.0/lib/armv6vfphLinux3.xgcc4.7.2:/home/pi/RTI/ndds.5.0.0/lib/armv6vfphLinux3.xgcc4.7.2jdk:/home/pi/RTI/ndds.5.0.0/lib/armv6vfphLinux3.xgcc4.7.2jdk
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.rti.ndds.config.Version.get_core_library_build_number_string()Ljava/lang/String;
    at com.rti.ndds.config.Version.get_core_library_build_number_string(Native Method)
    at com.rti.ndds.config.Version.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.rti.ndds.config.Version.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at simpledds.MonitorDicoveredInformation.start(MonitorDicoveredInformation.java:37)
    at simpledds.MonitorDicoveredInformation.main(MonitorDicoveredInformation.java:312)
```

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error indicates that the dynamic libraries for RTI Connext DDS (e.g. libnddscore.so and others similarly named) are not found in your load library path.

From your target directory name (armv6vfphLinux3.xgcc4.7.2) it appears you are running on a Linux platform. In that case the environment variable that needs to be set to add to the load library path is called LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  The name you are using DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH is the correct name for the MacOS platform but not for Linux.

Gerardo